# Using custom objective function for trained/saved XGBoost model

Tags: python, xgboost

I have a custom objective function I am passing to an XGBoost model during training, which works great.

The function is:

```
def weighted_binary_cross_entropy(label, pred):
    # assign the value of imbalanced alpha
    imbalance_alpha = 90
    # compute the prediction with sigmoid
    sigmoid_pred = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-pred))
    # gradient
    grad = -(imbalance_alpha ** label) * (label - sigmoid_pred)
    hess = (imbalance_alpha ** label) * sigmoid_pred * (1.0 - sigmoid_pred)

    return grad, hess
```

and I am invoking it as per:

```
xgb_test = XGBClassifier(objective=weighted_binary_cross_entropy) \
    .fit(
        X_trainnorm.to_numpy(),
        y_train.to_frame().to_numpy()
    )
```

When I save the model using the `save_model` method, however, the attribute in the saved JSON for objective is defaulting to `"binary:logistic"`...

I found this, which describes how model I/O works: [saving_model](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/saving_model.html) that states "XGBoost accepts user provided objective and metric functions as an extension. These functions are not saved in model file as they are language dependent features... Another way to workaround this limitation is to provide these functions again after the model is loaded."

I have not been able to figure out how to apply the custom objective function AFTER I load the model. If I do the obvious thing, like:

```
fname = "name.json"
file = os.path.basename(fname)
model.load_model(fname)
model(objective=weighted_binary_cross_entropy)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'XGBClassifier' object is not callable
```

Comment: What if you just do `model.fit(...)`?

Comment: It could be something like model.objective = weightedbinarycrossentropy

Comment: `model.fit(objective=weighted_binary_cross_entropy)` gives: 
`TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'objective'` ... (which makes sense, since `objective` is not data to fit).

Comment: Figured it out! I'll post the answer after I test it.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than I thought:

```
model = XGBClassifier()
print(model.objective)
```

produces

```
binary:logistic
```

and

```
model = XGBClassifier(objective=weighted_binary_cross_entropy)
print(model.objective)
```

produces

```
<function weighted_binary_cross_entropy at 0x7fa89c953f70>
```